# How can I select the letter beside a text cursor with Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, caret

I'm using jQuery and Lettering.js to wrap each letter in an `<h1>` with a span and give it a unique ID. I've also set `contenteditable=true` on the `<h1>` so when I click on it I can edit the text. How would I select the `<span>` element that is either to the left or right of the cursor, so I could apply styling to it?

Here's my code

```
<head>

    <style media="screen" type="text/css">
        body {text-align: center}
    </style>

    <script src="scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="scripts/lettering.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function(){
             $("h1").lettering();
         });
    </script>

</head>

<body>

<h1 contenteditable="true" >Click me!</h1>

</body>
```

Would really appreciate any help or advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will work in all major browsers:

```
function getCaretContainerElement() {
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            var container = sel.getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer;
            return container.nodeType == 1 ? container : container.parentNode;
        }
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" &&
               document.selection.type != "Control") {
        return document.selection.createRange().parentElement();
    }
    return null;
}

var h1 = document.getElementById("foo");

h1.onkeyup = h1.onmouseup = function() {
    var caretContainerEl = getCaretContainerElement();
    if (caretContainerEl) {
        // Do stuff here
        alert(caretContainerEl.id);
    }
};
```

Here's a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/BATGH/1/

Answer (score 1):

Adding a click event to each of the paragraph tags created by the lettering script will give you the element that was clicked on.  Then you can use either [prev](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) or [next](http://api.jquery.com/next/) method to get the letter before or after the letter that was clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("h1 p").click(function(){
        alert($(this).prev().html());
    });
});
```

I worked up an example that will show an alert with the previous letter. http://jsfiddle.net/5n5vJ/

Comment: That's great thanks! Would it be possible for this to happen if I use the arrow keys to move around the text? So if I click, it will give me the letter, but then if I key left it will move the caret and give me the previous letter too?

Comment: In fact, since the caret/cursor is always going to be within a span, is it possible to just get the ID of the current span it is in?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another library called [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) which could work for you. Check out the additional module CSSClassApplierModule. It lets you wrap a selection in a class for styling.

Comment: thanks but I need the styling to be applied to the id's created by Lettering.js